# Asignar posiciones para convertir a un decimal

Tags: c#, sql

Buen día a todos, espero y me puedan ayudar por que no puedo avanzar.

Tengo un checklistbox que se rellena con sp y se activa mediante checkbox, el sp me trae los siguientes valores:

```
 Text                                  SwitchId     Switch
Búsqueda de direcciones                   0            1
Historial de ruta                         1            2
Funcionalidad de Geocercas                2            4
Generación de reportes                    3            8
Alertas                                   4           16
Disparo de inmovilización                 5           32
Comando de cambio de tasa de transmisión  6           64
Administracion de conductores             7           128
Soporte MDT                               8           256
Puntos de Interés                         9           512
Localización Web                          10          1024
Salida SMS                                11          2048
Configuración de recursos                 12          4096
Reportes Programados                      13          8192
Capacidades de Administrador              14          16384
Comandos de MDT                           15          32768
Fleet 360                                 16          65536
Móvil Habilitado                          17          131072
Cuenta visualizadora                      18          262144
Visualizador de Conductores               19          524288
Desactivar la actualización del 
  cuentakilómetros                        20          1048576
Contador de Horas                         21          2097152
SEGURIDAD EN MANEJO                       22          4194304
Gestión de Tareas                         23          8388608
Gestión de Jerarquías de Subcuentas       24          16777216
Asignación Dinámica de Subcuentas         25          33554432
Gestión de Grupos de Vehículos 
  de Subcuentas                           26          67108864
Gestión de Alarmas                        27          134217728
Gestión de riesgos                        28          268435456
Tablero                                   29          536870912
RSS Enabled                               30          1073741824
Tablero de control Pointer                31          2147483648
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada uno de los clientes que manejamos en el area, tiene asignado un numero que es el siguiente (ejemplo) Swich =  523263, este numero convertido a Binario sería el siguiente (1111111101111111111) y corresponde a los switchs que se encuentran activados a cada uno de los clientes, para cada uno de ellos es de manera dinamica y no todos, tienen lo mismo activado.

Lo que a mi me gustaria es que cuando el cliente se seleccionara de un droplist,  automaticamente se activaran los switchs para lograr el numero que corresponde al numero binario. Es decir, cada texto tiene asignado un valor en el switch y este obtiene un valor que sumados todos me brindan el valor total de los permisos activados.

Espero haberme explicado de manera concreta, ¿Alguien sabe como podria conseguir mi meta?.

Gracias.

Comment: No mi amigo, se como convetir a binario es un ejemplo que te indica cuales estan activados..

Comment: Ok, disculpame. A ver si me explico, el switch es el campo, es decir los que esten activados corresponden a la posición que tiene el valor en el campo. Si tu sumas todos los valores que podrían estar activados, te daría el numero que agrego al inicio. ¿Me explico?

Comment: Dame un momento y la edito para agregar mas información, gracias. Listo gbianchi... a ver si les puedo dar mas explicación. Agregue una imagen...

Comment: gbianchi, a ver que te parece la imagen que agrego adicional, es a donde quiero llegar...

Comment: Si si.. ahora se entiende lo que queres.. como estan definidos los checkbox?? suponiendo que ya tenes el binario en binario (que ya dijiste que si) es solo un problema de vista.. lo que necesitamos ver es como construis esa vista, para saber como tildar los checks que necesitas.. es wpf o winforms?

Comment: windforms mi hermano, es una aplicación web. Los checkbox se llena con un sp

Comment: eh.. winforms no es una aplicacion web.. es una app asp.net en todo caso.. para poder marcar los check, tenes que poder identificarlos. Parece cansador, pero si te hubiera escrito de una, tenes que usar la propiedad tag del control check e iterar uno por uno en los child del form, no hubiera sido lo que querias. Por eso hay que ser claro con las preguntas. ;)

Comment: O sea.. como identificas tus checkbox en la pantalla?

Comment: Lo que sucede es que textos se vinculan con los campos "SwitchId" y "Switch", la aplicación se esta trabajando sobre una aplicación Web.

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente lo puedas resolver haciendo 2 elevado a cada posición tildada, o sea, sería algo así:

```
double res = 0;
foreach (int pos in checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices)
    res += Math.Pow(2, pos);
```

Espero te sirva.

Suerte!